# Can we restore backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition?

Tags: sql-server

I need to restore backup taken from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition. Is it possible ?

Comment: And in what edition was the backup taken? Standard, Enterprise, Developer?

Comment: I think if you configure the database compatibility level and then back up, it might be possible.
Otherwise I don't think so.
Try posting this at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can only restore backups to servers running the same or higher version. Normally you can restore backups on SQL Express that were made on servers running other editons (Standard, Enterprise, ...) as long as the database size is not greater than the max size supported by SQL Server Express (10GB on latest versions).

In your case, the backup was made on a server running SQL Server **2008 R2** (version **10.50**) and you are trying to restore it to a server running SQL Server **2008** (version **10.00**).

Comment: As long as the database size is not greater than the max size supported by SQL Server Express and **as long as the database does not use any feature that SQL Express does not support** (like partitioning)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 and later, some Enterprise Edition–only features make a database Enterprise Edition–only (i.e., it can’t be restored on a Standard Edition or lower SQL Server system) if the features are present in the database.